# What changed in .net 4.0 to scenarios when TransactionScope escalates to DTC?

Tags: ado.net, .net-4.0, transactionscope, msdtc

Can someone detail the changes made in .net 4 to the circumstances under which TransactionScope will (and will not) escalate to DTC?  Or is everything the same as 3.5?

Comment: Why do you suspect that there were changes made?

Comment: nice username!  I suspect changes because I vaguely remember someone saying that there were improvements in 4.0 (I think tied to Sql Server 2005)

Comment: just stumbled across this question now , maybe you meant lightweight transactions like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163527.aspx) ? its not since .NET 4.0 though.

Comment: Perhaps!  I can't remember now =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not listed anywhere on MSDN as having been changed so I'm going to say it's the same.

Comment: I vaguely remember someone saying that there were improvements in .net 4 that avoided escalation to DTC.

Comment: alright...seems that no one can come up with changes, and since MSDN doesn't list any there must not be any changes.  bounty is yours for answering first!

Comment: -1: not finding it in MSDN doesn't mead there have been no changes. This answer is absolutely un-informative.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find any documentation about changes (found this thread as I was looking for some myself), but it sure seems anecdotally that something that changed.

We had a .Net 3.5 app with about 100 unit tests that used TransactionScope. My team allows telecommuting, and I found that no matter what I did, these tests failed when I was working remotely, over VPN. Had no issues with them locally. Previous research I'd done indicated there were some issues with DTC over VPN, but it wasn't worth the hassle of digging deeper.

However, we upgraded the project to .Net 4.0 last month and since then I've had no issues with these tests over VPN. Could be a change in our VPN, I don't deny, but the timing is at least very coincidental.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, there is no such changes. Why MS would break thousands of project which are using TransactionScope? Maybe you misunderstood something (or the source you were reading was not accurate), as not every dbms has TransactionScope's support and in that case, TS becomes a distributed transaction.

P.S. Sorry for my English :-)

Comment: How would those projects break?  If .net is better at escalating only when it has to, then the code simply does not escalate in more cases.  that should make existing projects run faster, right...but not break them.

Comment: I mean that behavior is not changed in any way, otherwise of course it would break backward compatibility.